# Error de sintaxis y al compilar v-model junto a: value en VueJs

Tags: html, vue.js

Buen día con todos. Estoy aprendiendo Vuejs, pero no encuentro por ningún lado como arreglar mi problema, agradecería que me ayuden como solucionarlo, gracias; 'dentro de un formulario, hay un input, dicho input tiene un valor según el arreglo, pero al ponerle un v-model para que envie el dato vía vuejs, al compilar da un error. es lógico que no estoy haciendo bien en unir v-model y :value en un input en vue.js, pero busqué su solución y no logro encontrar por ningún lado, les agradezco por su tiempo :), solo deseo que que el input tenga el valor de cada alternación y ese valor lo envié por el formulario.
Adjunto el error

> :value="arrayPregunta.numPreg" conflicts with v-model on the same
> element because the latter already expands to a value binding
> internally

```
<div v-for="arrayPregunta in arrayPreguntas" :key="arrayPregunta.id" class="carousel-item">
  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" @submit.prevent="postRespuesta">
    <input v-model="numPregunta" type="text" class="form-control-file" :value="arrayPregunta.numPreg">
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes utilizar v-model ni :value de forma simultánea, tendrás que eliminar uno de ellos.

Recuerda que tienes las propiedades computadas y el @change en caso de utilizar :value.

Comment: podrías explicarme con un ejemplo por favor? no soy muy bueno con Vue.js o en este caso como lo seria?

Comment: Tienes que eliminar v-model o :value, no puedes tener los dos al mismo tiempo. En el caso que desees eliminar v-model perderás la reactividad de Vue, osea no podras detectar cambios, por eso lo puedes complementar con @change="funcionDetectarCambios"

Comment: En resumen o utilizas v-model o utilizas :value pero no los dos

Comment: gracias. investigaré sobre el particular